# How to fix these arch linux errors

Tags: linux, arch-linux, error-handling

**So i run this command `sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb`
to check errors and i got a lot of these errors . how to fix these ?**

```
Jul 17 13:46:27 tanuj kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

Jul 17 13:46:27 tanuj kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

Jul 17 13:46:45 tanuj gnome-session-binary[448]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

Jul 17 13:46:45 tanuj gnome-session-binary[448]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

Jul 17 13:47:26 tanuj gdm-password][752]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Jul 17 13:47:36 tanuj systemd[765]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed

░░ Defined-By: systemd

░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.

░░ The job identifier is 442 and the job result is failed.

Jul 17 13:47:39 tanuj gdm-launch-environment][425]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Jul 17 13:47:50 tanuj systemd-coredump[1407]: [] Process 517 (wireplumber) of user 120 dumped core.
                                              
                                              Module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id d3c210522f2d619f9e3c2d7196aaa6ec2037e14b
                                              Module libasound.so.2 with build-id aefb908044b1b408df406f1a9bab9bba486c0e94
                                              Module libspa-alsa.so with build-id 95ba39ea2b77b562303c1c6acf9d660316cfdd29
                                              Module libudev.so.1 with build-id 2a20e10475325f65fa29687073270e417e20a984
                                              Module libspa-v4l2.so with build-id a1b081d21c73fdc1ba75be7457f018be044fd257
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-logind.so with build-id ba06b6aa5616f6a27e7bc94143b1e2ddb826d73d
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-si-node.so with build-id d3ae5b8221764926c5208963f148db21267d4f06
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-si-audio-adapter.so with build-id 80df3b6fbbb005acfb16719951a36bf28b1188a6
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-si-audio-endpoint.so with build-id 8748a763fd09decf36703562a79545da0f96d04d
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-mixer-api.so with build-id 6c98529d81973729faa2b7a21d9e54cc46023b91
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-si-standard-link.so with build-id 36695a978542b89cad22db5789a596734bdecf89
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-default-nodes-api.so with build-id 0c2eb814a76f554cd91cede590c746a02de16ed1
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-default-profile.so with build-id cdff4dacc78a130d7a2ed21923bead1bab199650
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-portal-permissionstore.so with build-id 1a798a1f3ebfce36fe6ee4f2e29ec17c3e399063
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-metadata.so with build-id 2aba1d6959c5469e64a395e0603dbf2c6f38e823
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-file-monitor-api.so with build-id 032224a0ce97c7b1b02ebb5e962263ffbf85d3ba
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-reserve-device.so with build-id 7e6cafc74c530b638502f3256864adf6c9b8c204
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-default-nodes.so with build-id cbb060d8f6ec036d6bddc719732b5532380e2897
                                              Module libgvfscommon.so with build-id 2cfa9a05d5e376857a2dacaf4893238a88eefb9e
                                              Module libgvfsdbus.so with build-id f6f918ab413a1eaaa77134863653c4382b7cf8de
                                              Module libm.so.6 with build-id 1b7296ef9fd806e47060788389293c824b09ad72
                                              Module libdl.so.2 with build-id 94198b268228074fa9f405bbedbbae94112593ed
                                              Module liblua.so.5.4 with build-id 7bdd0ca9ab751d85d87f9f5cc170c7a7a9b7f08f
                                              Module libwireplumber-module-lua-scripting.so with build-id 5b466456e157ae2b3365c115fca7fcf5795cfdae
                                              Module libpipewire-module-session-manager.so with build-id d4eb1f6da947a0b1cafa9aa61ebb7035d70bdc24
                                              Module libpipewire-module-metadata.so with build-id 0d83f77bc77fec4d798e7c8101521e9bf49c5230
                                              Module libpipewire-module-adapter.so with build-id 1efec9f4584c9cde173075db54d20b9bf533477e
                                              Module libpipewire-module-client-device.so with build-id d99e3f14314ce45b15d1a94d45828f6a7295c835
                                              Module libpipewire-module-client-node.so with build-id e27ba1627fd9d769bebb39c6123e32e84817c430
                                              Module libpipewire-module-protocol-native.so with build-id 38658ba97ba061becbaa6974faad95e01d60525e
                                              Module libpipewire-module-rt.so with build-id 8d396d31b674d1e20049257612ecee0c0d50c806
                                              Module libgpg-error.so.0 with build-id 4738b8a9478177c202cccd64e0eb65d3dea2bfae
                                              Module liblz4.so.1 with build-id e63600ab23b2f6997f42fac2fa56e1f02ce159a1
                                              Module libzstd.so.1 with build-id ab54c2881f53ab314e134f3e08c76d504376dd5d
                                              Module liblzma.so.5 with build-id 28b40c7af8098a66af6ee093b6986b91cad7694d
                                              Module libgcrypt.so.20 with build-id 8bf3cb884124273640de797a3e77d86c98434ea4
                                              Module libcap.so.2 with build-id 21b00ab76bb16fde56fd741f07233c78069f0579
                                              Module libsystemd.so.0 with build-id 3e5d9eb54ba96616b0f90c9b897f04fd126527de
                                              Module libdbus-1.so.3 with build-id 7f4b16b4b407cbae2d7118d6f99610e29a18a56a
                                              Module libspa-dbus.so with build-id 9f4e1bcbc6a903ea88028a84ff03b1c641059f87
                                              Module libspa-support.so with build-id ac45ac61b6e9900c8a54ba6e179d75e8bd55b5f5
                                              Module libblkid.so.1 with build-id 140694a62d8d4d07c6c320a501f948dd1b389d73
                                              Module libpthread.so.0 with build-id 95ae4f30a6f12ccbff645d30f8e1a3ee23ec7d36
                                              Module libmount.so.1 with build-id 4436aeea0cd8c01b5a77969e0531184f8b3513ce
                                              Module libz.so.1 with build-id fefe3219a96d682ec98fcfb78866b8594298b5a2
                                              Module ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with build-id 0effd0e43efa4468d3c31871c93af0b7f3005673
                                              Module libpcre.so.1 with build-id 845483dd0acba86de9f0313102bebbaf3ce52767
                                              Module libffi.so.8 with build-id f0a9586cf0f42d2b9971bd1065ca3a6b19f4a2c2
                                              Module libgio-2.0.so.0 with build-id 7a769ec24a9a705d04ee0297730032f70ed0835b
                                              Module libgmodule-2.0.so.0 with build-id abd986222e2cf12fc7324cb0182dfc2c8f2269c0
                                              Module libc.so.6 with build-id 60df1df31f02a7b23da83e8ef923359885b81492
                                              Module libgcc_s.so.1 with build-id 0e3de903950e35ae59a5de8c00b1817a4a71ca01
                                              Module libpipewire-0.3.so.0 with build-id 26f221f18b965f0eef3aa6565228b42dec8e105f
                                              Module libglib-2.0.so.0 with build-id 1340f3a762b2293ebf6d725edf0eb14839f85317
                                              Module libgobject-2.0.so.0 with build-id a7515bd8cd51064d187953c0f506a43958de31a6
                                              Module libwireplumber-0.4.so.0 with build-id 17b8c335baab325582cfa41d42d282bcb696a185
                                              Module wireplumber with build-id 0d4af843b78c77316d55948702a956e98989edf6
                                              Stack trace of thread 517:
                                              #0  0x00007f374294af21 n/a (libwireplumber-0.4.so.0 + 0x25f21)
                                              #1  0x00007f37422d9544 n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xa4544)
                                              #2  0x00007f37422d957d n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xa457d)
                                              #3  0x00007f37427ddc6b g_main_context_dispatch (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x54c6b)
                                              #4  0x00007f3742834001 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab001)
                                              #5  0x00007f37427dd1cf g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x541cf)
                                              #6  0x000055d2f07e62f2 n/a (wireplumber + 0x22f2)
                                              #7  0x00007f3742429290 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x29290)
                                              #8  0x00007f374242934a __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x2934a)
                                              #9  0x000055d2f07e65a5 n/a (wireplumber + 0x25a5)
                                              
                                              Stack trace of thread 538:
                                              #0  0x00007f3742511c9e epoll_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x111c9e)
                                              #1  0x00007f37421794e9 n/a (libspa-support.so + 0x144e9)
                                              #2  0x00007f374216bd01 n/a (libspa-support.so + 0x6d01)
                                              #3  0x00007f37426e8de7 n/a (libpipewire-0.3.so.0 + 0x3fde7)
                                              #4  0x00007f374248c54d n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c54d)
                                              #5  0x00007f3742511874 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x111874)
                                              
                                              Stack trace of thread 657:
                                              #0  0x00007f3742505c3f __poll (libc.so.6 + 0x105c3f)
                                              #1  0x00007f3742833f68 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xaaf68)
                                              #2  0x00007f37427dd1cf g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x541cf)
                                              #3  0x00007f374233dacc n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x108acc)
                                              #4  0x00007f374280d405 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84405)
                                              #5  0x00007f374248c54d n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c54d)
                                              #6  0x00007f3742511874 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x111874)
                                              
                                              Stack trace of thread 1405:
                                              #0  0x00007f374250b30d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x10b30d)
                                              #1  0x00007f374282e063 g_cond_wait_until (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xa5063)
                                              #2  0x00007f37427ac8d3 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x238d3)
                                              #3  0x00007f374281063b n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8763b)
                                              #4  0x00007f374280d405 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84405)
                                              #5  0x00007f374248c54d n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c54d)
                                              #6  0x00007f3742511874 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x111874)
                                              
                                              Stack trace of thread 541:
                                              #0  0x00007f3742505c3f __poll (libc.so.6 + 0x105c3f)
                                              #1  0x00007f3742833f68 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xaaf68)
                                              #2  0x00007f37427db392 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x52392)
                                              #3  0x00007f37427db3e2 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x523e2)
                                              #4  0x00007f374280d405 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84405)
                                              #5  0x00007f374248c54d n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8c54d)
                                              #6  0x00007f3742511874 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x111874)
                                              ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64

░░ Subject: Process 517 (wireplumber) dumped core

░░ Defined-By: systemd

░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

░░ Documentation: man:core(5)

░░ Process 517 (wireplumber) crashed and dumped core.

░░ This usually indicates a programming error in the crashing program and
should be reported to its vendor as a bug.

Jul 17 16:56:13 tanuj sudo[16624]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed

Jul 17 16:56:13 tanuj sudo[16624]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [tanujrarh26]
```

Comment: For one make sure you don't partial update. That *might* be *one of* the reasons that wireplumber crashes.

Comment: Is your system up to date?

Comment: yes my system is up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different errors, not just one, it's hard to say what's going on on your side. Do any of these errors actually bother you? If not, there's no need to worry, think of them as informational messages. Most modern feature-full desktop OS'es dump a ton of errors at runtime and no complex software nowadays is really fool-proof. Fixing all the errors takes more time while you need to give up on more pressing issues.

If you run `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` you'll see even more errors from the kernel. Doesn't necessarily mean something on your system is malfunctioning.